Is there a way to summarize all calls of given function in memory_profiler?
I'm using memory_profiler to analyze the memory consumption of some data processing script I'm using. However, one of the function I used is called many times, and the basic usage of memory_profiler seems to show memory increment for every call to this function.
Is there some way to get a summary of what memory the function uses across all calls to said function ?
Below a small snippet
import memory_profiler
import random

alldatas = []

@memory_profiler.profile
def someprocessing():
    global alldatas
    somedata = [random.uniform(0,1) for i in range(10000)]
    alldatas.append(somedata)


if __name__=="__main__":

    for i in range(10):
        someprocessing()

What memory_profiler gives me :
runfile('/home/user/python/memorytest.py', wdir='/home/user/python')
Filename: /home/user/python/memorytest.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    14    176.0 MiB    176.0 MiB           1   @memory_profiler.profile
    15                                         def someprocessing():
    16                                             global alldatas
    17    179.9 MiB      3.9 MiB      100003       somedata = [random.uniform(0,1) for i in range(100000)]
    18    179.9 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       alldatas.append(somedata)


Filename: /home/user/python/memorytest.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    14    179.9 MiB    179.9 MiB           1   @memory_profiler.profile
    15                                         def someprocessing():
    16                                             global alldatas
    17    183.7 MiB      3.9 MiB      100003       somedata = [random.uniform(0,1) for i in range(100000)]
    18    183.7 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       alldatas.append(somedata)


Filename: /home/user/python/memorytest.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    14    183.7 MiB    183.7 MiB           1   @memory_profiler.profile
    15                                         def someprocessing():
    16                                             global alldatas
    17    187.6 MiB      3.9 MiB      100003       somedata = [random.uniform(0,1) for i in range(100000)]
    18    187.6 MiB      0.0 MiB           1       alldatas.append(somedata)

And what I would like to get (the XXXX indicates info I do not care about) :
Filename: /home/user/python/memorytest.py

Line #    Mem usage    Increment  Occurrences   Line Contents
=============================================================
    14    XXXXX MiB    XXXXX MiB           1   @memory_profiler.profile
    15                                         def someprocessing():
    16                                             global alldatas
    17    XXXXX MiB     11.7 MiB      300009       somedata = [random.uniform(0,1) for i in range(100000)]
    18    XXXXX MiB      0.0 MiB           3       alldatas.append(somedata)

Note that it's possible memory_profiler is not right tool for what I want, and I don't mind using another tool (though every google search I made for line-by-line memory profiling sends me back to memory_profiler)
